# Qemu doesn't load my Image file at my specified address

Tags: linux, arm, qemu

My linker script:

```
SECTIONS{
    . = 0xC0008000;
    __text_start = .;
    .text :
    {
        boot/start.o
        *(.text)
    }
    __text_end = .;
    .rodata ALIGN(4) : {*(.rodata*)}     
    .data ALIGN(4)   : { *(.data) }    
    __bss_start = .;    
    .bss ALIGN(4)  : { *(.bss)  *(COMMON) }    
    __bss_end = .;
}
```

0xC0008000 is the address of bootloader, and I want to specify it in QEMU. 
Here is what I've tried. \

```
    qemu-system-arm \
        -machine virt \
        -cpu cortex-a15 \
        -nographic \
        -S -s \
        -m 4096M \
        -kernel Image \
        # -device loader,file=Image,addr=0xC0008000
```

It will set the PC at 0x40000000 and after few instructions, PC will jump to the bootloader at 0x40010000. This is acceptable according to documents offered by QEMU, but it is not what I expect to do.

> RAM starts at 0x4000_0000 https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/arm/virt.html

But when I change the command to

```
    qemu-system-arm \
        -machine virt \
        -cpu cortex-a15 \
        -nographic \
        -S -s \
        -m 4096M \
        -kernel Image \
        -device loader,file=Image,addr=0xC0008000
```

The image is loaded correctly, and it seems to be duplicate instructions in 0x40010000 of the instructions in 0xC0008000, but it can't jump to 0xC0008000 which makes hard to debug.
I wonder why the PC won't be able to jump to where I expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what format your Image file is. Is it an ELF file, or a raw binary? I'm guessing from the described behaviour that it's a raw binary.

If you pass QEMU the `-kernel` option you are saying "this file should be started the way the Linux kernel expects to be started". That means, among other things, that you don't care where in the memory map it is placed, and that it should be started by first setting up a few registers and then jumping to the start of the image. (There is an exception: ELF files are loaded according to where the ELF file says they should be placed, and started by jumping to the ELF entrypoint. But ELF files are better loaded with the generic loader these days.)

(The specifics of what "boot me like a Linux kernel" means are listed in [this bit of the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/Booting). The virt board will always pass a device tree blob, not ATAGs.)

If your Image file is not expecting to be booted like a Linux kernel then you should not use the `-kernel` option.

Instead, you can use the generic loader (`-device loader`). Your second command line gets this almost right, but it is wrong in two ways:

1. you haven't removed the `-kernel` option, so your image file will be loaded by QEMU twice, in two different places. This is just confusing, so delete the `-kernel` option.
2. to get the generic loader to set the starting PC for the CPU you need to explicitly ask for that. Since the starting PC you want is the same as the image load address, you can do that with `-device loader,file=Image,addr=0xc0008000,cpu-num=0`. The cpu-num part says which CPU to set the PC for. (There is more complicated syntax for setting the PC to some other address than the image load address if you need it.)

Note 1: the above is for raw image files. If you have an ELF file then the generic loader will load the file to the addresses the ELF file specifies and you don't need to specify `addr=`. It will use the ELF entrypoint for the initial PC if you use `cpu-num=`.

Note 2: 4GB of RAM for a 32-bit CPU is rather a lot. The Cortex-A15 has LPAE, so it's not like it's impossible to access the part of RAM past the 4GB physical address mark, but it seems odd. 3GB (i.e. ram from 0x4000_0000 to 0xFFFF_FFFF) might be just as useful and save on how much of your host's resources the VM is using.

Comment: 1. The image file is a raw binary. 
2. I'm actually porting linux-0.11-x86 to ARM for assignment, so I guess this file should be started the way the Linux kernel expected to be started?
3. I've deleted the -kernel option, and the Image file is loaded where I expect to be, but new problem occurs-the PC stuck at 0x0 with infinite ``andeq`` instructions which is all 0s. How to fix the problem?
4. How can I specify the ram address range in QEMU? I just found that the docs for QEMU are quite hard to understand so I turn to stackoverflow for help :C
Thanks!

Comment: If the PC ends up at 0 then this probably means your code took an exception, and you haven''t set up the exception vectors correctly yet. You can debug that kind of early crash with either the QEMU gdbstub or with some of the debug logging under the -d option. You can't specify where RAM is in QEMU -- as with real hardware, it is in a fixed location and the OS has to deal with that.

Comment: I've used QEMU gdbstub and this is how I found out that PC ends up at 0x0. When I use `-kernel` option, I found that there are few instructions at `0x40000000` which PC is initialized as, leading to `_start` which is the entry of the operating system. But with `-device loader ...`, PC ends up at 0x0. 
Instruction I mentioned at `0x40000000`:
`0x40000000 mov r0 #0`, `0x40000004 ldr r1, [pc, #4]`, `0x40000008 ldr r2, [pc, #4]`, `0x4000000c ldr pc, [pc, #4]` then it jumps to `_start`. 
I guess this piece of code is what is missing using `-device loader ..` instead of `-kernel`.

Comment: The 0x4000_0000 stuff is if you are using the "boot like a Linux kernel". You don't want that. If -d in_asm,int prints the first instruction as 0x0000_0000 then you forgot the 'cpu-num=0' suboption. If it starts at 0xc000_8000 but then quickly ends up at 0 then you took an exception in your guest code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-kernel` option qemu will perform the following:

1. Load the kernel image at address (`0x40010000`)
2. Set the PC to starting of the DRAM base (`0x40000000`)
3. Start executing the instruction (these instructions are set by QEMU):

   - Load the DTB address into the X0 register
   - Jump to the starting location of your kernel image(`0x40010000`)

Now if you want to transfer your kernel image and start execution without performing the above then the below command will be used:

To transfer kernel at a particular location: `-device guest-loader,addr=<addr, where you want to copy img>,kernel=<kernel_img_path>`

To load the PC at the start of the kernel: `-device loader,addr=<addr, where you copied your img>,cpu-num=0`